# Show that the function is continuous on R

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the function defined by $$f(x)= \cases{x\ln|x| &if $x \neq 0$\\x = 0&otherwise}$$ is continuous on R.

I have shown by a theorem that the function $g(x) = x\ln|x|$ is continuous on the domain $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

However, I am unsure of how to combine this with $h(x) = 0$, when $x = 0$. My approach was to show both functions defined by $f$ are continuous on their respective intervals, thus showing $f$ is continuous on the whole real line R. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you really want to show is that $$\lim_{x \to 0} x\ln|x| = 0$$ That means that if you want to extend $g$ to a continuous function on the whole number line, then it can be done, and $f(0) = 0$ is the only viable choice.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thank you so much!